# CRON expression to next DateTime with T-SQL on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cron

I have a column that contains a CRON expression that represents how often a user has to perform a task. I would like to build a view that lists the date and things to do for a given user. But I need to calculate my next CRON occurrence in a datetime in T-SQL. How interpreted my expression CRON in SQL?

example:
column value = [0 30 8 1 *?]

I would write:
SELECT CrontabSchedule ( '0 30 8 1 *?', GETDATE ()) FROM dbo.UserTasks

Someone has a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function within SQL server to genrate Next date based on Cron expression. Only way would be, implemeting cron exprssions in C# and genrate it as dll,then regsiter DLL with SQL server CLR.

Refernces:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e0ebe5a-d452-4893-bcef-0a1e2520c076/convert-cron-expression-to-datetime?forum=transactsql

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/SQL-Server-Crontab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14734226)

Comment: If you look at my response, I proivided answer for the question. Those links are just refernce.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can give you a hint: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/117285/tsql-sql-function-for-a-cron-expression.html

The UDF presented in the link is as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Q117285.CreateJobScheduleFromCronExpression
     @CronExpression varchar(200)
     , @FieldDelimiterCharacter char(1) -- any whitespace character
 AS
 BEGIN;
     DECLARE @CronExpressionArray TABLE
     (
         Seconds varchar(50)
         , Minutes varchar(50)
         , Hours varchar(50)
         , DayOfMonth varchar(50)
         , Month varchar(50)
         , DayOfWeek varchar(50)
         , Year varchar(50)
     );
     INSERT @CronExpressionArray
         SELECT
               [Seconds]    = [1]
             , [Minutes]    = [2]
             , [Hours]      = [3]
             , [DayOfMonth] = [4]
             , [Month]      = [5]
             , [DayOfWeek]  = [6]
             , [Year]       = [7]
         FROM
         (
             SELECT ds.ItemNumber, ds.Item
             FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@CronExpression, @FieldDelimiterCharacter) ds
         ) pSrc
         PIVOT
         (
             MAX(pSrc.Item)
             FOR pSrc.ItemNumber IN
                 ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
         ) pvt
     ;
     SELECT * FROM @CronExpressionArray;
 END;
```

The DelimitedSplit8K UDF was extracted from the article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar and eventually built my own [tSQLcron](https://github.com/kgeorge314/tSQLcron)

Currently it isn't SET based as it is a stored-procedure. An example usage is

```sql
    DECLARE @out_is_cron_true BIT ;

    EXEC tSQLcron.usp_is_date_in_cron_period
      @cron_expression =  N'* 0/15 * * * *' -- nvarchar(100)
    , @validate_date = '2020-01-01 13:15:00' -- datetime
    , @out_is_cron_true = @out_is_cron_true OUTPUT -- bit

    IF (@out_is_cron_true = 1 )
    BEGIN
      PRINT 'DO SOMETHING';
    END
```